# H5P JS content files are being corrupted

Tags: javascript, nfs, h5p

***see update below***

I'm running a WordPress server in a docker container (latest).  I've installed the H5P plugin.  The docker container has persistence on a TrueNAS server.  RW permissions are all working.  My problem is around file corruptions and is limited to content development in H5P and stored as js/css in `wp-content/uploads/h5p/cachedassets`.  All other site css and js is functional.

The content that I'm creating with the H5P plugin is stored in corrupted css and js files.

Here is an example of a css file (abbreviated):

```
.joubel-simple-rounded-button:active .joubel-simple-rounded-button-text {
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
}
�����....����sform: rotate(45deg);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

And here is an example of a js file:

```
}(H5P.jQuery));
;
�����....����alogContainer);
/**
 * Get the DOM element
 * @return {HTMLElement}
 */
```

The browser shows the following errors:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token (at VM21001
9a153c63c945d6b0ca6a625d7d71f1a7f8b6dc29.js:160:1)
[This is the js file referenced above.]

h5p.js?ver=1.15.7:976 Unable to find constructor for: H5P.TrueFalse 1.8

h5p.js?ver=1.15.7:1115 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined 
(reading 'getCopyrights')
```

What I've tried:

a)  Uninstalling and reinstalling WordPress and the H5P plugin.

b)  Clearing the browser cache, persistence files (on the NFS) and the mySQL `chachedassets`.

c)  About 4 hours of research (with [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dFDBtmapSSg) being the only relevant hit; which didn't solve the problem)

Some observations:

Each time that the `cachedassets` files are generated (using the same content) the invalid characters are generated in different locations and of different lengths.  The characters are also replacing other css and js text.  In other words, it is replacing text (this is why I'm pointing out the NFS in case that's relevant).

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

I recreated the entire stack on a local docker server with local storage and the files are saved correctly.

**This leads me to believe that this is an H5P saving files to a TrueNAS NFS issue.**

Comment: NFS isn't very fault tolerant, so an unstable connection could be the cause of file corruption. I have never experienced this issue before (on any H5P platform that I set up), yet never used H5P on a TrueNAS NFS. But I can shed some more light onto what the "cachedassets" are. They are single file bundles of all JavaScript/CSS files that an H5P content needs to speed up loading (rather from the pre-HTTP/2 era). Adding `define("H5P_DISABLE_AGGREGATION", true);` to your `wp-config.php` file should disable that caching, so your page should at least work. Doesn't fix the issue though.